# how to make my numpy array unique by axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i have a numpy array like the XY coordinates here below:

```
2d_coords = [
[1,2]
[1,1]
[2,1]
[3,1]
...
]
```

either [1,1] or [1,2] need to go (doesn't care which one) , only one point on the X coordinate is possible.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) would be helpful. For example,

```
import numpy as np

l = np.asarray([
    [1, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 1],
])

_, unique_indices = np.unique(l[:, 0], return_index=True)  # get the indices with unique x coordinates
print(l[unique_indices])
```

The example output:

```
[[1 2]
 [2 1]
 [3 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external library, you can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
d_coords = [[1,2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]

new_list = [d_coords[i] for i in range(len(d_coords)) if d_coords[i][0] not in [k[0] for k in d_coords[:i]]]

# new_list: [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
```

NOTE: don't start variable names with numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]])
plot_coords = coords[np.unique(coords[:,0])].T

plt.plot(plot_coords[0], plot_coords[1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

What about pandas?

```
pd.DataFrame(coords).drop_duplicates(0).values

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```